# How to do Element wise product torch?

Tags: torch

How do i find an element wise product of two tensors? Both my tensors are of the same dimension and i want to find their product?

```
q
 1  2  3
 2  4  6

w
 1  2  3
 2  4  6
```

It should yield:

```
1   4   9
4  16  36
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using cmul.

```
th> torch.cmul(q,w)
  1   4   9
  4  16  36
```

As a side note:

`q:cmul(w)`: will multiply them and store the value back into q,

`z=torch.cmul(q,w)`: will multiply them and return a new tensor which will be stored in z.